# Can not display the image which its path comes from database

Tags: codeigniter, file-upload

I have a form which successfully upload a picture to a folder and save its full path to database.But when I want to display the image nothing is shown.
This is one of the uploaded image's path in database:

```
/home/webuser/public_html/traincms/upload/koala.jpg
```

this image saved in a folder of server.what should I do to display the images?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution.My upload path was

```
$path=dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']).'/upload/';
```

I saved this path to database.When I want to display the image on browser it did not display it with this path.I uploaded the image with above path but I saved this path to database:

```
$image_path=base_url().'/upload/'.$_FILES['pic']['name'];
```

now I can upload and display the images successfully.

Answer (score 0):

You should use HTTP path of image, if you are using `codeigniter` then try this way

```
<?php echo img("traincms/upload/koala.jpg"); ?>
```

OR

```
<img src="<?php echo base_url("traincms/upload/koala.jpg")?>" />
```

Hope your code will store in `public_html` directory

Comment: @setara, what you exact mean.. do you want to display image on browser?

Comment: @setara, way in answer correct, make sure `koala.jpg` image exist in `traincms/upload` dir and although have you set path `$config['base_url'] = ??` in `application/config/config.php` file

Comment: yes `koala.jpg` exists in `traincms/upload` folder and the `$config['base_url']` is correct.